# "chroot", but with a VM?

Tags: backup, rsync, qemu, backup-restoration

I just backed up a remote system using rsync. I have a directory that I can `chroot` into and would now like to boot it up as a VM. I know that `qemu` has `-kernel` capability, as well as `-drive file=fat:` [virtual FAT](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Devices/Storage#Virtual_FAT_filesystem_(VVFAT)) feature. I was hoping that maybe with `-append` and a bit of modifying of /etc/fstab I could boot the thing up, but unfortunately the early tests suggest a problem with device files in the backup directory:

```
# kvm -kernel boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-99-generic -drive file=fat:`pwd`
qemu-system-x86_64: -drive file=fat:/home/d33tah/workspace/hakierspejs/backup/mounted: Could not read directory /home/d33tah/workspace/hakierspejs/backup/mounted/dev/fd/12
```

What other options do I have if I want to have the image bootable with minimum hassle after each iteration of backing up? I'm looking for a "set up once, use often" use case.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual FAT is just a FAT filesystem type indeed. Its not a linux ext filesystem so it's not really possible to boot it from there. Not at least without a lot of modifications.

You can follow this step by step to prepare new image in a file container:

1. `dd if=/dev/zero of=/some/path/some/file.dat bs=1M count=[SIZE_IN_MB]M`
   This will create a new empty file of SIZE_IN_MB Mb size.
2. `mke2fs /some/path/some/file.dat`
   This will create ext filesystem inside that file.
3. `mkdir /mnt/newimage && sudo mount -o loop /some/path/some/file.dat /mnt/newimage`
   This will mount your file with ext fs to /mnt/newimage.

Then you can rsync/copy your backup data there. Once done, you can umount that image. Also check to detach loop bind with `losetup -d /some/path/some/file.dat`. Now you have a proper ext fs image inside /some/path/some/file.dat, you can try booting with QEMU of it (it's of the type RAW).

Another (and better way) is to migrate your original system to QEMU VM. Backing up & restoring VMs is much easier and add more consistency to your backups.

Answer (score 0):

I asked around and it looks like there's no easy way out of the situation - except for maybe booting via NFS or other similar hacks. Here's how to quickly create an ext4 drive from a source directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail
set -x

FNAME=ext4image.bin
SRCDIR=source-directory
DSTDIR=temporary-empty-directory

mkdir -pv $DSTDIR
truncate -s 20G $FNAME
mkfs.ext4 -F $FNAME
mount $FNAME $DSTDIR
tar cf - $SRCDIR | pv | tar xf - --strip=1 -C $DSTDIR
umount $DSTDIR
```

Assuming that you have all of the mounts in a single filesystem now, the first step is to modify `/etc/fstab` so that it only contains the following:

```
/dev/root / ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Now you can use the script above to create an ext4 image. You can boot it the following way:

```
kvm ext4image.bin -kernel mounted/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-99-generic -append root=/dev/sda -initrd mounted/boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-99-generic -m 2G
```

Kernel version may obviously vary.